# print multiple values for same parameter from an std object response

Tags: php

I would like to print the values of [UpdateDescription] from both shipments in [0] and [1]

Here is the request sent

```
$auth_call = $soapClient->TrackShipments($params);
```

Shipments numbers are sent in the $params array

the response is below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Transaction] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Reference1] => 
            [Reference2] => 
            [Reference3] => 
            [Reference4] => 
            [Reference5] => 
        )

    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [HasErrors] => 
    [TrackingResults] => stdClass Object
        (
            [KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Key] => 52398174132
                            [Value] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [TrackingResult] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [WaybillNumber] => 52398174132
                                            [UpdateCode] => SH005
                                            [UpdateDescription] => Delivered
                                            [UpdateDateTime] => 2016-09-26T14:45:00
                                            [UpdateLocation] => New York
                                            [Comments] => Maz
                                            [ProblemCode] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Key] => 43559827323
                            [Value] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [TrackingResult] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [WaybillNumber] => 43559827323
                                            [UpdateCode] => SH008
                                            [UpdateDescription] => Shipment on Hold
                                            [UpdateDateTime] => 2016-09-28T10:18:00
                                            [UpdateLocation] => New York
                                            [Comments] => Na
                                            [ProblemCode] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am currently able to print the value of [UpdateDescription] using the below when theres only 1 shipment as [0] and [1] are not there in the response

```
$description = $auth_call->TrackingResults-KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY->Value->TrackingResult-UpdateDescription; 
print_r($description);
```

Comment: how can i do that Frayne ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a `foreach`-loop:

```
foreach($auth_call->TrackingResults->KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY as $tracking_result) {
    print_r ($tracking_result->Value->TrackingResult->UpdateDescription);
}
```

Comment: Again `print_r()` is not doing what is asked for

Comment: Yup, the value of `[UpdateDescription]` not all the contents of the array it lives in

Answer (score -2):

Have you try

```
$description = $auth_call->TrackingResults-KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY[0]->Value->TrackingResult-UpdateDescription; 
print_r($description);

$description = $auth_call->TrackingResults-KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY[1]->Value->TrackingResult-UpdateDescription; 
print_r($description);
```

you can also interact with a foreach.

I hope this help you

Comment: I think you should expand on the _you can also interact with a foreach._ as that is the most likely thing the OP wants to do. A `print_r()` is not really helping OP at all

Comment: You should use a `foreach` loop. That's only hard coded and is not dynamic for multiple tracking results not exactly matching count of 2